# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentActQueue$1.isBatchingLegacy')

Tags: node.js, react-native

BUNDLE ./index.js

LOG Running "MyApp" with {"rootTag":1}
ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentActQueue$1.isBatchingLegacy')
ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactCurrentActQueue$1.isBatchingLegacy')
`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using expo please use an older version of react-native(0.65)
2. Create a new project and move your code there.

Please refer to this thread,
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34079

Comment: Am using react native .. not expo

Comment: This much detail is not enough to debug, I suggest you start a new react-native project and see if the same error is happening.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your `react` dependency version synchronously in `packages.json`

for example:

```
"react": "18.0.0",  
"react-native": "0.69.3",
```

Comment: What exactly does this mean?

Comment: This answer helped me. I did the following: `yarn add react@latest`. Which installed React 18.2.0 and solved the issue.